# How to fetch value for a particular key in angularfire2?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

[image: firebase Data structure]

This is the structure of database, I have to fetch one `value('UID')`.

```
this.af.database.object('/profile/' + this.uid).subscribe(profile => {
  console.log(profile);
  this.uid = profile.uid;
  console.log(this.uid);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
this.af.database.object('/profile/' + this.uid).subscribe(profile => {
var obj = {};
profile.forEach(item => {
obj[item["$key"]] = item["$value"];
});
console.log(obj);
});
```